# How to get current company id odoo 15?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I've try this:

[('company_id','=',company_id)]

self.env.company_id

self.env.user.company_id

But those all 3 ways are leaded to default company, but not current company.

[image]

Comment: Check in `self.env.context`

Comment: @MuhammadYusuf sir, is there anyway to call `self.env.context` inside of domain of record rules?

Comment: Yes, try something like this

 `<field name="domain">[('company_id','in',context.get('allowed_company_ids'))]</field>`
OR
`[('company_id', '=', context.get('company_id'))]`

Comment: @MuhammadYusuf not working sir, it say `ValueError: <class 'NameError'>: "name 'context' is not defined" while evaluating
"[('company_id','in',context.get('allowed_company_ids'))]"`

Comment: Sorry in record rules there will not be context will be where the is an active model
in ir.rule you can use `            <field name="domain_force">[('company_id','=',[user.company_id.id])]</field>
`

Comment: @MuhammadYusuf so we have to use python code to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating a `related` field that points to the current company or just creating a new stored computed field `show_field_XY`. In the _compute method you can access the context like this:

```
self.env.context.get('company_id')
```

Finally, just access that field in the domain and you should be good to go.

Comment: thanks you for comment, i'll try and reply asap

Comment: sir, i've try your solution but with domain of record rule such as `['|',('company_id','=',company_id),('company_id','=',False)]`, how do you call that new field?
for example, we defined that field is "current_company", how to call it? we can't set `('company_id','=','current_company')`

Comment: You need to remove the quotes: `('company_id','=',current_company)`. 
Also add the field itself with `<field name="current_company"/>` (you can make it invisible if you want to). Also make sure the field is computed if still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
current_company = self.env.user.company_id
```

Comment: sir, where do you use this?

Comment: i'm trying to get current company in record rule domain, it's xml file tho.

Answer (score 0):

As i check, if we use context to get current company, and in case we using multi company, we can only get the first company.

In that case, we should use company_ids to get all the companies of user instead.

Example:

```
['|',('company_id','in',company_ids),('company_id','=',False)]
```

Hope it's help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `self.env.company` ? You could use a separate field to determine this and use that in your xml..

```
active_company_id = fields.Many2one(
        "res.company",
        string="Company",
        default=lambda self: self.env.company,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create record rules for your module like the following,
and make sure in your class model you have the `company_id` set up already:

```
<!-- Rules --><record id="yourmodullid_comp_rule" model="ir.rule"><field name="name">""" multi-company</field><field name="model_id" ref="model_yourmodel" /><field name="domain_force">['|',('company_id', 'in', company_ids),('company_id','=',False)]</field></record><!-- ___________ -->
```